# Breakdown with existential type and higher order function

Tags: scala, existential-type

Using some structure:

```
object Foo {
  trait Bar[B]
}
trait Foo[A, B, F <: Foo[A, B, F]] {
  def baz(fun: A => Foo.Bar[B] => Unit): Unit
}
```

...why are existential types causing trouble:

```
def test[A, F <: Foo[A, _, F]](foo: F) =
  foo.baz { a => b => println(b) }
```

The following error occurs:

```
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A => Foo.Bar[(some other)_$1(in type F)] => Unit
   forSome { type (some other)_$1(in type F) }
 required: A => (Foo.Bar[_$1(in type F)] => Unit)
         foo.baz { a => b => println(b) } 
                     ^
```

While the following compiles:

```
def test[A, JamesClapperSociopath, F <: Foo[A, JamesClapperSociopath, F]](foo: F) =
  foo.baz { a => b => println(b) }
```

Answer (score 1):

It must have something to do with equivalence of existential types. The compiler probably infers `b: F#_$1` and then can't figure out that the two projections are equal.

Fortunately, functions are contravariant in the parameter type, so you can just write:

```
def test[A, F <: Foo[A, _, F]](foo: F) =
  foo.baz { a => (b: Any) => println(b) }
```

Comment: At that point you might as well use `a => (b: Foo.Bar[_]) => println(b)`, which also compiles.

Comment: @TravisBrown Sure, it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately the `println` is just a placeholder. Of course, I need to preserve the type `Foo.Bar[B]`. I was more interested in _why_ this is happening. Meanwhile, my refactored thing is `trait Foo[A, F <: Foo[A, F]] { type B }` which produces less PITA. The `baz` arg is then of type `A => Foo.Bar[F#B] => Unit`.